# How does a battery work?

Tags: electrostatics, electricity, batteries, electrochemistry

How does the positive terminal of the battery attract electrons? Does the electric field emitted by the positive terminal attract the electrons?

Comment: You got it, jut be careful with words like "emitted" and electrostatic fields. A battery produces an electrostatic field between its two poles. Charge carriers are experiencing a force in this electrostatic field. When they move trough the entire field, they will have work equivalent to the voltage times their charge performed on them by the battery. As a result, a battery is a device that stores energy.

Comment: This seems like a question that could be answered easily by typing "battery" into google (and ignoring the hits to the criminal offence)